# Model View Projection causes distortion

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have a cube in my world that i am translating by 0.0f, 0.01f, 0.0f every frame however this causes the cube to [become very distorted](https://youtu.be/cN-4_SI1xAk?t=6s)

I am 99% sure that this is an issue with MVP, being how I set it up, multiply the variables or so other factor relating to it. This is how I have set up each variable, The Model matrix is sent to the shader every frame update and the Camera and Projection matrix are sent once when the window loads.

Source: http://pastebin.com/FsY0GS6K

**Camera, Projection & Model matrix**

```
m_cube_matrix = Matrix4.Identity;

m_camera = Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(2.0f, 2.0f, -1.5f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
int _u_camera = GL.GetUniformLocation(m_shader.m_shader_program_id, "uCamera");
GL.UniformMatrix4(_u_camera, false, ref m_camera);

m_projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.5f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 10.0f);
int _u_projection = GL.GetUniformLocation(m_shader.m_shader_program_id, "uProjection");
GL.UniformMatrix4(_u_projection, false, ref m_projection);
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 uModel;
uniform mat4 uCamera;
uniform mat4 uProjection;

in vec3 vPosition; 
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec3 oNormal;
out vec3 oPosition;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = uProjection * uCamera * uModel * vec4(vPosition, 1);

   oNormal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * vNormal);
   oPosition = vPosition;
}
```

Comment: I answered your question, but you should still edit the question to provide the relevant code parts, and maybe directly inline some some still image from the video.

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation matrix is *transposed*.

You use the same matrix functions for all of your matrices, but send the `m_cube_matrix` as transposed to the GL, while you don't do that for all others.

From your code:

```
GL.UniformMatrix4(_u_model, true, ref m_cube_matrix);
//                          ^^^^ you are transposing your matrix here
```